# Unique lab entry populated across multiple tabs

Tags: ms-access, tabs, ms-access-2007, subforms

I am creating a DB from scratch using my 2 weeks of experience with MS Access 2007 (what the hospital has...) in order to track research patients.  The basic flow of information will be such that from a start screen, the person can either enter a new patient or find an old patient (each from a button) - Got those parts... (They go to a Patient Demographics form)

Upon finding the patient, they can either select a previous visit from a combo box  (got that part) or create a new visit (from a button that then pops-up an addition form for the combo box) - Got that part... (They go to the Visit Form)

This is where my problem is.  Once on the Visit Form, we need to be able to generate Lab entries (with each lab entry having multiple tables to store the data).  I have created the form ( Patient info area and 12 tabs each with different subforms in datasheet view (except one)) and I can get current 'fake' results that I entered in the tables to come up in the tabs.  My problem lies in getting it so that when we enter a new lab date in any one of the tabs (which DOES generate a new unique LabID) to have it populate that date across the other 11 tabs (all associated with that unique LabID) and record in each base table.  If the Visit has no labs associated with it, my subforms should be just blank datasheets with the ability to put in a new labID.  Otherwise if we're already in a visit, the subform datasheets should display all previous unique LabID's and values associated with that visit AND have a line to enter a new lab incident.
Oh yeah....  We also have to be able to go back into those other lab records and edit/add to them as results become available (pathology takes much longer than others - etc.).  However if the LabID and associated date populates across each of the forms in all 12 tabs there should be a blank space waiting for that info when it becomes available.  So that might not be much of an issue.

Essentially a Unique Patient will generate Mulitiple Unique Visits  -->  Each Visit can generate 1 or more Unique LabID's which are then associated with MANY lab data points (all unique TO THAT Lab ID).  Confused yet?  If I've got it right in my head, it's a one to many to many to one relationship?

Here's part of my relations table:

[image]

Here's the Visits Form:

[image]

For each of the subforms in the tabs of the Visits Form I have the 'Link master Fields' set to VisitID, and the 'Link Child Fields' set to Lab ID.  I have managed to do all of this with a surprising little amount of VBA coding, but here's the coding that gets me from the combo box on the patient demographics page:

```
Private Sub VisitCBO_Change()
    Dim ptWHERE As String
    ptWHERE = "[VisitID] = " & Me.VisitCBO.Value
    DoCmd.OpenForm "NewVisitsF", acNormal, , ptWHERE, acFormEdit
    VisitCBO = Null
End Sub
```

As of right now, there is no code in my builder for the visits page.  The subforms are based on queries pulling from the lab group tables and the labID tables.

I have been scouring the web and the Access 2007 Bible for answers for a bout a week, but I can admit when I'm WAY over my head and stuck... Specialists, please help! - I can provide a link to the DB if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is VisitsT your parent form and each of your subforms somehow go through an LabsT form.  Your parent/child should link your main VisitsT data to each of your subforms, but right now it looks like you're going through LabsT and linking the wrong field.   From your join relationships, it looks like LabID = LabID (parent/child), however you don't have them linked.  Each of your subtables should have a unique key (perhaps LABID and VISITS) and it looks like you tried to do this with that middle LabsT form.  This info should be repeated on every subform.  Then your parent/child can be on VisitID only.

Comment: So the LabsT should have a combo key that uses LabID and Visit_ID?  And then I'll need to put Visit_ID in each of the subtables?
And then set the parent(VisitT)/child(LabsubT) links to VisitID/Visit_ID?

It's imperative that each of the subtables (Vitals/Chem10/CBC....) are all associated with each other (theoretically by the same LabID).

PatientA  -->  Visits A  -->  Lab entry A  -->  Labs(A, ,C,D)
                                                          B  --> Labs (A,B,C)
                               B  -->  Lab entry A  --> Labs (F)

Comment: Boy...  That last one didn't format like I was expecting...  Anyway, the last bit of it was making sure that regardless of which lab value is entered it will generate a lab ID for all the lab-subtables...

Comment: I'm thinking your LabsT table is not necessary.   If VisitID is in each of the subtables, then that unique VisitID is recorded in each of the subtables based on the parent/child relationship, whenever the record on the subform is updated.  However, I just went through a similar scenarios where having multiple subtables can be more headache then it's worth (i.e. when archiving etc), so I update for just one big subtable that contained all the fields.  Then you can just create subforms based on the fields you need from that one big subtable - this also solves the generation of LabID.

Comment: I'm thinking your LabsT table is not necessary.   If VisitID is in each of the subtables, then that unique VisitID is recorded in each of the subtables based on the parent/child relationship, whenever the record on the subform is updated.  However, I just went through a similar scenarios where having multiple subtables can be more headache then it's worth (i.e. when archiving etc), so I opted for just one big subtable that contained all the fields.  Then you can just create subforms based on the fields you need from that one big subtable - this also solves the generation of LabID.

Comment: But each Visit can generate multiple lab entries....  Think of it like this...  Some patients will be admitted to the hospital generating a REDICULOUS number of lab data points (each time we sample the data generates a LabID).  Others (and later in time - the same patients) will be seen at the office which will generate very small numbers of data points.  If the LabsT goes away, will we still be able to have multiple lab samplings on the same hospital admission?  Or will it generate another visit?

Comment: DemographicsT has key PatientID (lose the VisitID from this table).  VisitT has unique ID - PatientID/VisitID.  The subtables then have unique ID - LabID/VisitID????

Comment: This may be totally crazy, but what if we did something like this?  https://1drv.ms/i/s!AscQMt6xbnLWkfUN9TlsHOrnqIQWwQ  
  It creates a 1:many relation with the VisitT:Labsubtables, a 1:1 relation with the LabT:Labsubtables and a 1:many relation with the VisitT:LabIT......  You think that might keep all the LabID's the same while relating the LabID to the VisitT in a one to many relationship?  It looks so messy I'm thinking no, but my first set up was cleaner and I couldn't get it to work either....

Comment: But each Labsubtable would then generate it's own unique ID and the labs wouldn't be associated unless they were all on one mile long table.  I was hoping to compartmentalize to aid in problem solving...  But if it is causing more problems then maybe just one giant massive subTable is the way to go.  Then we split everything up in the forms...

Comment: I think I get where you're going.  Forget all this, and let's go back to the beginning...  As long as LabID is the child to the LabsT.LabID parent, then everything should be okay.  Basically the parent/child should be the same field in both tables (and of same type/size too).   Note that the LabID won't necessarily be present in each of your subforms/table unless that record is updated in each subform.

Comment: My goal is that when someone opens a new visit (or old visit) and puts in just one lab value not already associated with a previous LabID, (regardless of which subtable) it will spawn that same LabID in ALL subtables so that there is a date(same as all the other subtables) and a bunch of empty boxes streaming off to the right in subtables that don't have data (yet)...    THAT is what I haven't been able to find a solution for.

Comment: Yup. I get it.  Just make sure your LabID in each subform is the child to the parent LabID in the LabsT parent form. It should work.

Comment: And then it's just a matter of getting each subform to refresh after a value is entered?

Comment: Yes.   Any update to the record will autopopulate the child field with the parent value.  Note that your parent form (Visit Form?) now contains the unique LabID though.   If you need another LabID, you'll need yet another main form (i.e. patient form) that opens the Visit form.

Comment: I think what I'm missing is a subform....  The Tabbed subforms should all be within another subform of the LabT.  So the sequence is VisitF(Parent)  -->  LabsF(sub)  -->  Tabbed LabGroupsF (subsub).  Then I have parent/child from visit to labs, and from labs to tabbed-labgroups.  Essentially a Parent to grandchild relationship structure.  Then the relationships and parent/child structures should take care of everything else...  yes?

Comment: parent -- grandchild would work also, but you can do in two different ways.  (1)  Grandparent-Parent is one form, that opens up another form Parent-Child.  (2) Or have the Grandparent have a listbox/combobox that is the link the child subform.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up plastering all of the data subtables back into one huge table that contains all the lab variables and then divided up the variables into tabbed subforms.  The Parent/child relationship is now VisitID/Visit_ID between the VisitT and LabsT.

I'd still like to know how to do this with the data split into different tables as in my original question as it's easier to conceptualize that data that way.  SO if anyone has any ideas, PLEASE let me know!

Thanks to geeFlo for our back and forth in helping me get to a working form and process!

Comment: Splitting tables will work the same way.  You either end up with subtables that have no record (i.e. you have subtables that are not applicable to the main table) or you can force a record to every table by creating a loop through all your other subtables after a record is updated in any one.  (Perhaps name your tables numerically, so you can do a simple iteration through all your "other" subtables assigning an the same parent ID to those subtables.)

Comment: I'd love to know the code for that!  Like I mentioned in the OP, I only have 2 weeks of experience with Access and VBA so I'm still a fledgling trying to create a skyscraper nest. I imagine it would be something like a if... then... until... else... type of statement?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.  If there is no entry (i.e. subtable is N/A for that record) then no record is required.   eg. John goes to school.  Of 10 subjects, he picks 4 and has to say "YES" to apply.  Each subtable has a Name, Applied field.   If John is the record on main form, and 10 subform for 10 subjects with the appropriate parent/child linkage (John = John).  Only when he fills in the [Applied] field, does the subform table get filled with a record (i.e. John, Yes).   For tables where he didn't bother to fill out, there are no records for John.  (cont...)

Comment: (...cont)  If you want to backfill (John, No) values in the other tables, then you can use FOR-Next to loop through all your tables, and fill in (John, No) wherever it doesn't exist.  This is either done with an UPDATE query or you start playing with RECORDSETS to write these values in.

Comment: It's not that I need to have something put into every container in each subtable.....  It's that I need to have empty containers reserved in each subtable for that lab - in case we want to fill it in later, or if the results come back to us days after we generate the initial LabID and Lab date (generated synchronously).  That's really what generating the LabID across each subtable does...  It reserves a spot associated with that LabID.  Otherwise (cont...)

Comment: (cont...)  if I put in data in table A and it generates a LabID, but lets say we're waiting for the pathology report and the surgery transcription to be posted (which takes sometimes 2-4d).  When I go back to these different subtables, not only will there have been other patients generating LabID's in the mean time, but it will generate a new LabID with both the surgery AND path report.  I'm trying to avoid all that by reserving positions in all subtables with one LabID.  Because they're all related to each other by when they were sampled.

Comment: I just saw a little snippet about the tags property....  On the surface it seems like it might be a way to make the LabID persistent between subtables.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The LabID generated for each subtable will still be unique to the parent and related to that specific instance.  i.e. when they were sampled.  So whatever triggers the parent form to open (or filter), you're either opening an existing instance for that patient, and able to fill out other subforms that you need.  For new patients/visit, then the new LabID is generated on opening the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up completely changing things around....  I deleted the LabID table completely and divided up the lab groups into separate tables each with their own labgroupID autonumber (CBCID, Chem10ID, etc.).  I don't like it, but it's recording data properly : labs are associated with visit by date and through the visit to the patients.  If I want to follow labs over time I'll do that in a report by patient then grouped by date.  Maybe some day I'll be able to figure out how to have one LabID that each of the labsubgroups belong to so that they'll all populate at the same time ...  Probably involves some heavy VBA coding.